# Why is this favorite appearing in my network proflile?

Tags: bug, bookmarks, network-profile, favorites-tab

I've noticed that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132301/11323) on Math SE is listed [under favorites in my network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/511905/kimball?tab=favorites), but not for Math SE account.  I don't recall ever favoriting it, except when I tried favoriting it and unfavoriting it to get rid of it (this did nothing), so I believe it should not be listed as a favorite under any of my accounts (the question also says 0 users have marked it as a favorite).

Is this a bug?  If not, what is going on?

Note: [I previously asked about this on Math SE Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/19450/11323) (now deleted) since I originally thought is appeared as a favorite on my Math SE account, but I didn't get any answers.

Comment: Yeah, for me [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/151159/status-of-the-x2-1-problem) is listed under favorites in my network profile even though I never clicked the star, only upvoted. Since favorite is just another kind of vote behind the scenes I guess something went wrong in the network profile synchronization, which took upvotes (vote id 2) as favorite vote (vote id 5) for a while. Did you upvote [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/132301/11323)? If so, when?

Comment: Hmm I have [this question](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10497/how-to-connect-another-database-from-magento) in my favorites and I don't recall I favourited it....

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, in fact according to my Math SE profile, I've never cast any votes on Math SE (which is shocking to me, though it's true I don't spend much time on that site).  Probably I did at least look at the question at some point...

Comment: @rene In my case & Shadow Wizard's the questions are only listed in our network profiles but not on our site accounts, but your question is also listed as a favorite on your magento site account, so maybe you accidentally favorited it or maybe it's a different issue?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that. Lets keep it as a signpost for now. I see nothing on that question that would make me visit that question. I searched in the tavern to see if it might have been mentioned but on its postid I only find [this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=2290112#2290112)

Comment: Four months later, it's still there.

Comment: (Now 11 months later)

Comment: It's happened to me too. It's happened on some of my own questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27997913/4284627)), on questions that I upvoted but didn't favorite ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277578/4284627), by the way I noticed that I actually wanted to favorite this one so I did, but it was listed in my favorite list on my network profile before I favorited it), and even on questions that I've never seen before ([example](https://meta.superuser.com/q/11591/513819)).