# Why is joining a Stack Exchange site required if you only wish to favorite a question?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

Say I want to favorite a question from a Stack Exchange site I haven't joined. I saw a question on the Fiction/Literature Stack Exchange site that I wished to favorite, but apparently I need to join said Stack Exchange site to do that. Why is that? Sorry if this is a duplicate; I did my best...ish to check if someone had already posted a similar question.

EDIT: If it's not obvious, the reason I'd like to favorite questions (from other stacks) is that it's a good source of new information. Obviously. I guess.

Comment: Oh, so you're complaining that you can't do actions that logged in users are supposed to do because you're not logged in? That's a bit weird.

Comment: I was merely asking what's the purpose of joining a community if I don't intend to be active on the community but only wish to favorite questions for learning purposes. I understand if it conflicts with the requirement that you have to join a community if you want to ask questions. An answer of "You can't do that because of X and Y" would have been enough for me.

Comment: Obviously there are ways to store the fact you favorite'd something without associating it to a specific user in a DB, but they certainly aren't as resilient as being stored online. That being said, what's wrong with a bookmark?

Comment: But where would your favorites show up then? Certainly not the network profile. It's usually a messy gathering of irrelevant communities.

Comment: Browsers have bookmarks.  You can use those to track web pages when an internal "favorite" function is unavailable.

Comment: I have lots of accounts on sites I have no knowledge of the topic to participate in... Some of them I join for "testing" purposes... others to upvote something that I agree with... there's no reason to **not** join a site that I can think of. Do you have a reason you're avoiding joining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that this is because favouriting is tracked in each site, like other actions (voting, editing, commenting). Each question has a favourited count, presumably, like with votes, favouriting is associated with the account. Like other users can see your edits and comments in your profile, they can see your favourite posts as well. Unlike edits, I think associating favourites with the Community account doesn't make sense. :)

Also, the favourites list shown in your network profile is messed up: [Why is this favorite appearing in my network proflile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248540/270345) While that might be a bug, a workaround is to visit your site profile for the correct list.

Answer (score 3):

Each site is only associated with other sites on the network through a very tenuous link. User accounts are for the most part separate on each site.

Favoriting a question is an action that is specific to you, i.e. it needs to be recorded against your user account.

If you don't have a user account (because they're mainly separate), then this can't happen.

If you really want to save a question for later without signing up, use browser bookmarks.